# Android: access SQLite database via Content Provider or implement DAO?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider, dao

I'm wondering which is the best approach to access my application database: use a Content Provider, or implement my DAO by hand?
From my latest investigations, seems that Content Provider, even for app internal use, is preferable, but I don't know exactly what are the drawbacks of each approach. 
Can you give some feedback about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I prefer to use [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)  if you have concerns of closing or locking of db. 
Check [Simple Content Provider for db operations](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.in/2011/11/at-last-i-concluded-it-is.html)

Comment: i am facing database is locked problem in multi-process. Should i use content Provider to solve that problem?

Answer (score 10):

From Google [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html).

> ### Before You Start Building
>
> Before you start building a provider, do the
>   following:
>
> Decide if you need a content provider.
>   You need to build a content
>   provider if you want to provide one or more of the following features:
>
> - You want to offer complex data or files to other applications.
> - You want to allow users to copy complex data from your app into other apps.
> - You want to provide custom search suggestions using the search framework.
>
> You *don't* need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is
>   entirely within your own application.

But then I got a bit confused when reading this and some other posts. Does it make sense to use content provider event if it is meant to be used only by your own app?

Comment: After all reading I decided to go to the content provider option. Things got easy in further development, for database management and syncing

Answer (score 5):

From the ContentProvider documentation:

Content providers are one of the primary building blocks of Android applications, providing content to applications. They encapsulate data and provide it to applications through the single ContentResolver interface. A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications. For example, the contacts data is used by multiple applications and must be stored in a content provider. If you don't need to share data amongst multiple applications you can use a database directly via SQLiteDatabase.

Seems to me that, if you're not going to share data with other applications, you do not need a content provider.

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

Comment: This is not relevant anymore since `ContentProvider` (event internal) is the best data source for `CursorLoader`)

Comment: Keep in mind that up to Android 4.2 content provider are by default available to other Android applications. Only since 4.3 default is exported:false